# Python check all values below are not None

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is the best way to check all values below are not None. This is what I have tried:

```
    user = url_string.get('user', None)
    subject = url_string.get('subject', None)
    email = url_string.get('email', None)
    from_address = url_string.get('from_address', None)

    if not any(user, subject, email,from_address):
        raise Exception('missing data')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you want all of them to be defined, the following code would be very pythonic. Since

> Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission. This common Python
>   coding style assumes the existence of valid keys or attributes and
>   catches exceptions if the assumption proves false. This clean and fast
>   style is characterized by the presence of many try and except
>   statements. The technique contrasts with the LBYL style common to many
>   other languages such as C.

https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html

```
try:
    user = url_string['user']
    subject = url_string['subject']
    email = url_string.get['email']
    from_address = url_string['from_address']
except KeyError:
        raise Exception('missing data')
```

As mentioned in the comments, this does leave open the possibility of one of the values in the dictionary being None and there for passing the test. However, I assume you are using `get('...',None)` on the assumption that the dictionary doesn't contain nulls. if it does indeed contain nulls, consider Moses Koledoye's solution.

Comment: That would be `KeyError`

Comment: It is also possible that the value **in the dictionary** is `None`. Based on the question, the condition should error as well...

Answer (score 4):

You can check for containment of `None` in an iterable of your variables:

```
if None in (user, subject, email, from_address):
    raise Exception('missing data')
```

Or better still put your code in a try/except with `KeyError` and raise your custom exception while handling the exception.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
if None in [user, subject, email,from_address]:
        raise Exception('missing data')
```